# Unable to get the Image/File to store in MySQL, byte array are stored in blob with length '0'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, blazor-webassembly

I have a blazor webassembly project that required to upload the files to the database. However I couldn't get the file to be store correctly. Am I missing anything?

Here is the code for the Controller:-

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FileController : Controller
    {
        private readonly FileUploadDbContext _fileUploadDbContext;
        private readonly IFileUploadServices _fileUploadServices;
        public FileController(IFileUploadServices fileUploadServices, FileUploadDbContext fileUploadDbContext)
        {
            _fileUploadDbContext = fileUploadDbContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fileUploadDbContext));
            _fileUploadServices = fileUploadServices;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UploadFileInfo>>> Get()
        {
            await _fileUploadServices.GetUplaodFile();
            return Ok("file get");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(IFormFile formFile)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                formFile.CopyTo(ms);
                var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
                // act on the Base64 data
                var fileinfo = new UploadFileInfo
                {
                    Data = fileBytes,
                    FileId = 1, //Ignore the 1, for testing purpose
                    FileName = formFile.FileName,
                };
                await _fileUploadServices.UploadFiles(fileinfo);
                return Ok("file created");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And Here is the code for my  Services:

```
public class FileUploadServices : IFileUploadServices
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<FileUploadDbContext> _contextFactory;

        public FileUploadServices(IDbContextFactory<FileUploadDbContext> contextFactory)
        {
            _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        }

        public async Task UploadFiles(UploadFileInfo uploadFileInfos)
        {
            using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {

                context.fileUploadInfos.Add(uploadFileInfos);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IList<UploadFileInfo>> GetUplaodFile()
        {
            using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                var uploadfiles = await context.fileUploadInfos.ToListAsync();
                return uploadfiles;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjqkj.png) while debugging, and also from the services also getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlKif.png).

This is the database [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocSIx.png). Please help me.

**Edited**

```
This is the Model: 

    public class UploadFileInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public int FileId { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public byte[] Data { get; set; }
    }
```

This is My migration(only had one since it is for testing):

```
public partial class mg1 : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AlterDatabase()
                .Annotation("MySQL:Charset", "utf8mb4");

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "fileUploadInfos",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    FileId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("MySQL:ValueGenerationStrategy", MySQLValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    FileName = table.Column<string>(type: "longtext", nullable: false),
                    Data = table.Column<byte[]>(type: "longblob", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_fileUploadInfos", x => x.FileId);
                })
                .Annotation("MySQL:Charset", "utf8mb4");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "fileUploadInfos");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is, you're assigning a Base64 string to `s` then never using it. Did you make some changes to the model and forget to fix them up (e.g. setting `Data` as `NotMapped` while you experimented with strings). Paste your code for `UploadFileInfo` and maybe check your migrations are up to date and applied and match your model.

Comment: Thanks @Tone, I checked and pasted the code in the post again. For the base64 string, I am just testing the Byte Array whether is it storing or no.

Comment: Hmm I've not done anything really with blobs but nothing is jumping out as being wrong. Sorry I've got nothing. All I can think is to do an Array.Copy to make sure it's nothing to do with the array getting disposed before saving somehow (can't see how, it looks ok) - actually never mnd you're already copying it.

Comment: Please do not delete and repost. You can [edit] your questions.

Comment: @HH I'm sorry, as I feel like there is too much to change. Do you want to stick with this thread or the old one?